# How to read base64 encoded picture from rails by android

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, base64

I want to send an base64 encoded picture from ruby on rails to android.
Sending the data to rails included the picture encoding and decoding works, the data transfer from rails back to android works also, but I can't decode the picture, which was encoded by rails. I always get a NullpointerException at the following marked line:

```
imageOutFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(imageString, Base64.URL_SAFE);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
**bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, imageOutFile);**
```

The encoded string looks like the following (it's the shortest one):

```
_9j_4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD_4Se-RXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAALAA4BAgAUAAAAkgAAAA8BAgAUAAAApgAAABABAgAJAAAAugAAABIBAwABAAAAAQAAAA==
```

Another string is this:

```
_9j_4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAAQABAAD_2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH_2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH_wAARCAHgAoADASIAAhEBAxEB_8QAHAABAQEBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAoICQcGAgED_8QARRAAAQIBCAYIBAQEBwACAwAAAAYHBQEECAkZOIe3AxQVFqfWAhhWV1iWl9cXaNXnERIjJRM2VfAkJic1UZSkUmchMjf_xAAXAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACQEH_8QAMxEBAAAEAwUGBQMFAAAAAAAAAAEGB1YCGJYDcbHV1ggXQUam8AURFjFRYaG1IYGRxcb_2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA_AIPwAAAAAAACo6rguPM3iPm-vCXEqOq4LjzN4j5vrwDbQAAAAAAABLnWM33Hqw4yoQ5UYS51jN9x6sOMqEOBiMAAAAAAAAqOq4LjzN4j5vrwlxKjquC48zeI-b68A20AAAAAAAAS51jN9x6sOMqEOVGEudYzfcerDjKhDgYjAAAAAAAAKjquC48zeI-b68JcSo6rguPM3iPm-vANtAAAAAAAAEudYzfcerDjKhDlRhLnWM33Hqw4yoQ4GIwAAAAAAACo6rguPM3iPm-vCXEqOq4LjzN4j5vrwDbQAAAAAAABLnWM33Hqw4yoQ5UYS51jN9x6sOMqEOBiMAAAAAAAAqOq4LjzN4j5vrwlxKjquC48zeI-b68A20AAAAAAAAS51jN9x6sOMqEOVGEudYzfcerDjKhDgbYsbvmb4PfdIWN3zN8HvukdtABxLsbvmb4PfdIWN3zN8HvukdtABxLsbvmb4PfdIWN3zN8HvukdtABxLsbvmb4PfdId
```

In Logcat I get a message like this, after the failed decoding:

```
--- decoder->decode returned false
```

I encode the string with the following method and send the string with a json object to android. The picture was uploaded with the uploader of CarrierWave.

```
Base64.urlsafe_encode64(File.read("public#{picture_path.to_s}"))
```

Comment: Manually decoding the provided example (after adjusting to compensate for the URL-safe encoding) does not appear to produce a valid image.  I can see a JPEG header, but cannot actually open the file as an image.

Comment: I have added another string, which was generated by rails. I"m trying to figure out, if the android reading or rails encoding is the problem.

Comment: Ok, I'm still struggling with the problem, but I found out some new stuff. The rails encoding doesn't seem to work as you also said. When I send this string with android to rails, i get the result you described. But when I send the encoded string created with android from rails to android, I don't get the right result also. So I still don't know, if the string works or if there's another error.

Comment: Ok, probably I struggle with 2 problems. The picture saving on android, which has already worked, and it's somehow still working, but not in the way, I wanted to have. And the encoding in rails, which doesn't work.

Comment: The picture handling problems just seem to exist in the emulator. So there's now again just the problem with the encoding in Rails or decoding in android

Comment: Regarding the encoding issue, my suggestion would be to remove the Android app from the picture entirely (since it's not related to the actual problem).  Instead, take the encoded strings Ruby is generated and plug them into something like [this](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/) until they come out correctly.  Then (and only then) hook it back up to the Android app.  Note that the decoder I linked to doesn't use/support the 'url safe' base64 variant you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the tip aroth, that's exactly what I did. Fortunately as you can see through my answer, after many wasted hours I was able to fix the bug. Thanks anywys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to read the file binary ("rb") and then encode it.

```
Base64.encode64(File.open("public#{picture_path.to_s}", "rb") {|io| io.read})
```

Comment: You may accept your own answer when it is the solution. The green hook is an improvement on user-friendliness. ;)

Comment: @sjas - He can, but I think he has to wait 48 hours first.